# flutter / dart How can check if a document exists in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to query using a bool if a document exists on the cloudfirestore or not. Unfortunately, my code does not work

I tried the following, but the bool does not change.

```
getok() {
  bool ok;
  Firestore.instance.document('collection/$name').get().then((onexist){
      onexist.exists ? ok = true : ok = false;
    }
  ); 
  if (ok = true) {
    print('exist');
  } else {
    print('Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe its because you're setting true instead of comparing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try doing it this way  though im usi IDS

```
//Declare as global variable

bool exist;

static Future<bool> checkExist(String docID) async {       
    try {
        await Firestore.instance.document("users/$docID").get().then((doc) {
            exist = doc.exists;
        });
        return exist;
    } catch (e) {
        // If any error
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42):

## Async / Await Function To Check If Document Exists In Firestore (with Flutter / Dart)

A simple async / await function you can call to check if a document exists. Returns true or false.

```
bool docExists = await checkIfDocExists('document_id');
print("Document exists in Firestore? " + docExists.toString());

/// Check If Document Exists
Future<bool> checkIfDocExists(String docId) async {
  try {
    // Get reference to Firestore collection
    var collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName');

    var doc = await collectionRef.document(docId).get();
    return doc.exists;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Found out that when a document Id does not exist it does not return false, it throws error!

Comment: just checked it does return false if document does not exist

Comment: What happens when it catchs an error, will the bool return an error or false?

Comment: @Dalon it will throw an error. doc.exists will return true or false, catch handles an error with communicating with Firestore. It is up to you if you want the program to continue as if it were false (so just always return false in the catch), or if you want to handle the error in another way (like show a custom error message).

Answer (score 6):

You could try this it works for me

```
Future getDoc() async{
   var a = await Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document($name).get();
   if(a.exists){
     print('Exists');
     return a;
   }
   if(!a.exists){
     print('Not exists');
     return null;
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to wait for the answer and second you always get an answer from the database. That means onexists does always exist.

You can check if the document exists with .documentID. Something like that:

```
try {
  var res = await Firestore.instance.document('collection/$name').get();
  print(res.documentID ? 'exists' : 'does not exist');

} catch (err) {
  print(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer checks if a document exit, and seek to update it with new data if it does exist. The below sample code is written in Flutter(dart).

```
Future uploadDataToFirestore(String docID) async {
var docSnapshot = await checkIfDocExist(docID);
if(docSnapshot.exists){
  try {
    await docSnapshot.reference.update(newData.toMap());
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO: Handle catched error here
  }
}
else{
  // TODO: execute some code here
}
```

}

Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>checkIfDocExist(String docID) async {
try {

```
  var doc = await collectionRef.doc(docID).get();
  return doc;
} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<bool> documentExistsInCollection(String collectionName, String docId) async {
    try {
      var doc =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).doc(docId).get();
      return doc.exists;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check if the document is exist in specific collection:

> ```
>  // check if ID exist
>   Future checkDocuement(String docID) async {
>     final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
>         .collection('collectionName')
>         .doc(docID) // varuId in your case
>         .get();
>
>     if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
>       // docuement is not exist
>       print('id is not exist');
>     } else {
>       print("id is really exist");
>     }
>   }
> ```