# How do I check data exists at firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a doctor appointment system, but when querying on firestore, "where" doesn't work at all. My code is ;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('appointments')
  .doc()
  .collection('pending')
  .where("doctor", isEqualTo: _doctorController.text)
  .where("date", isEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.parse(dateUTC + ' ' + date_Time)))
  .get().then((documentSnapshot){
    if(documentSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty)
      {
      print("errror");
      }
    else{
      print(DateTime.parse(dateUTC + ' ' + date_Time));
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('appointments')
          .doc(user.email)
          .collection('pending')
          .doc()
          .set({
        'name': _nameController.text,
        'phone': _phoneController.text,
        'description': _descriptionController.text,
        'doctor': _doctorController.text,
        'date': DateTime.parse(dateUTC + ' ' + date_Time),
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

my firestore

[image]

Comment: What error does `where` throw?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57882006/7278987

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.